# React component function cannot call another function

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use d3.js inside of a React app.

this.animateFirstStep gets called fine in componentDidMount but inside animateFirstStep, this.animateSecondStep never gets called.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

var d3 = require("d3");

export default class App extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {};
    }

    animateFirstStep() {
        d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .delay(0)
            .duration(1000)
            .attr("r", 10)
```

this one does not get called

```
            .on("end", this.animateSecondStep);
    }

    animateSecondStep() {
        console.log("hello");
        d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attr("r", 40);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.sampleSVG = d3.select(".d3")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 100)
            .attr("height", 100);

        this.sampleSVG.append("circle")
            .style("stroke", "gray")
            .style("fill", "white")
            .attr("r", 40)
            .attr("cx", 50)
            .attr("cy", 50)
            .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "aliceblue");})
            .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "white");})
```

this gets called fine

```
            .on("mousedown", this.animateFirstStep);
    }

    render() {
        return (<div className="d3"></div>);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try to add this.animateFirstStep = this.animateFirstStep.bind(this) ; this.animateSecondStep = this.animateSecondStep.bind(this) in constructor and try again? Not sure if that is the case, but you are referring 'this' in that function.

Comment: Try : `.on("end", this.animateSecondStep.bind(this));`

Comment: Open the chrome inspector, go to the "sources" tab, click "pause on exceptions", and check "pause on caught exceptions"

Comment: @MattYao tried it and i get this error
   `Uncaught TypeError: this.getAttribute is not a function

         at App.<anonymous> (bundle.js:40083)
 
        at App.tween (bundle.js:40150)
 
        at start (bundle.js:39918)
 
        at schedule (bundle.js:39859)
 
        at timerFlush (bundle.js:39724)
 
        at wake (bundle.js:39734)`

Comment: I haven't used d3 with React yet and can't do much help. Have you tried react-d3? I think it works better with React: (https://github.com/esbullington/react-d3/tree/master/src). Also, I suggest you change var d3 = require('d3') to import d3 from 'd3'; Because you are using ES6 here so you should use 'let' instead of 'var'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `d3.select` method requires a dom element. In the class method, `this` points to the React Component's instance, not the corresponding element. You should use a `ref` to first get the linked dom element and then pass it into the `select` method.

Comment: yep, this was the issue. i just moved the animateFirstStep and animateSecondStep to another file and called them inside the React Component and it worked.